# Python forcing hex escape into regex statement

Tags: python, regex, escaping

This question is in regards to how (and ultimately why) python includes a hex escape when it compiles a regex statement.

The regex statement (simplified) is as follows:

```
my_regex = re.compile('^((?:([bye])(?!.*\2)){3})$', re.MULTILINE)
```

I would expect this to find all combinations of the letters 'b','y',and 'e' (such as 'bye', 'yeb', 'eyb'). However, it finds all permutations, i.e. 'byy' 'bby' 'bbb' etc.

I finally discovered that python is converting the above expression into:

```
my_regex = re.compile('^((?:([bye])(?!.*\x02)){3})$', re.MULTILINE)
```

The difference is slight,

```
\2
```

versus

```
\x02
```

but it is enough to cause the results to include repeated letters.

How do I stop python from including the hex escape in the regex statement?  Why is it putting it there?  Furthermore, why does hex escaping cause repeating letters to match when otherwise they would not?

[hex escaped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ5O3.jpg)

[not escaped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMHRz.jpg)

Comment: `\2` is an _octal_ escape sequence. Python isn't putting it there, you did. ;) So you should use a raw string instead to stop Python from interpreting backslash sequences as escapes.

Comment: Amazing.  Thanks so much for putting an end to me banging my head on the wall.  A simple \\2 was all that was needed. Thanks!